# Minix 3.3 FTP connection via VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ftp, minix

I'm using Virtualbox 4.3 to run Minix 3.3 under my windows 7 installation... I have this file that I need to copy from windows to Minix. I searched around and I found out that FTP would be the way to go with it.
On my windows I have setup FileZilla Server, but when I try to `ftp localhost:2121`, that fails saying `Can't lookup  'localhost:ftp' : Non-recoverable failure in namame resolution`.
Any tips?

Comment: Does the Minix FTP client support the `hostname:port` notation at all?

Comment: it doesn't work even when i use `ftp localhost`